# SQL server index autotuning in Azure

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning

I know SQL server index autotuning available in Azure DB.  Which Azure DB version does this work with?  Also does this work for AWS SQLdb?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality isn't actually auto-tuning.  What happens is that Azure SQL DB will use any missing index recommendations and try applying those indexes and monitors the outcome to see if it has made improvements.

You should not rely on this to create all your indexes for you - it isn't that smart yet. This just helps with some you may have overlooked or changes in the access patterns on your database since it was designed and deployed.

Azure SQL Database as a PaaS service is always running the latest release of SQL Server so it is available for all databases hosted there.

It is also ONLY an Azure SQL Database feature at this stage so you will not have access to it with AWS RDS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this.  My company is trying to decide on AWS or Azure.  Auto index tuning is a key decision point.